# Jax rs enum deserialization case insensitive

Tags: java, jackson, jax-rs

I have a rest web service that consumes a json request:

```
@PUT
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response processRequest(Request request)
```

The request is a list of updates:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Request {
    @XmlElement
    private List<Update> update;
}
```

and the Update class has an enum field:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Update implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;

    @XmlElement(name = "Status")
    private Status status;
}
```

Status is an enum:

```
@XmlEnum
public enum Status  {
    @XmlEnumValue("active")
    ACTIVE("active"), 
    @XmlEnumValue("cancelled")
    CANCELLED("cancelled"); 
}
```

I would like the strings "active", "Active", "ACTIVE", ... to be deserialized into the enum ACTIVE but all tries failed: the status field is null in the Update java object (the conversion from String to enum fails with Active or ACTIVE input strings)

I tried to create a custom deserializer but not sure I did it well:

```
@Provider
public class IgnoreCaseDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Status>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public IgnoreCaseDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected IgnoreCaseDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Status deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return Status.fromString(jp.getValueAsString().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

and I added @JsonDeserialize annotation:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=IgnoreCaseDeserializer.class)
@XmlEnum
public enum HopperStatus
```

what am I doing wrong?

thanks for your help

Comment: You are mixing JAXB and Jackson APIs. Your endpoint suggest you expect JSON formatted request and respons, however your Request and Response beans are using JAXB (XML) APIs.

Comment: I couldn't find the JAXB way to do this, so I tried with jackson. How can I do it with JAXB only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Advices first. If you announce XML elements and attribute as upper case, you'd better announce all elements and attributes as upper case. So

`@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class Request`

`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Update")
public class Update implements Serializable {`

`@XmlElement(name = "Updates")
    private List<Update> update;`

*For primitive types and String, we usually announce them as `@XMLAttribute`, for classes and enum, we announce them as `@XMLElement`.*

and you should attach request XML content, this is important. I create it based on your defination.

```
<Request>
  <Updates>
    <Update>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Status>active</Status>
    </Update>
  </Updates>
</Request>
```

And for `active`, `ACTIVE` or `Active` request content conversion, I suggest you use [XMLAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html).

```
public class StatusAdapter extends XMLAdapter<String, Status> {
    @Override
    public Status unmarshal(String status) throws Exception {

        return Status.fromValue(status.toLowerCase()); /* ensure status is not 
           blank, or you should check null before toLowerCase(). Usually, `required` is
     set in XML annotations, eg @XMLAttribute(name = "name", required = true) */
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(Status status) throws Exception {

        return status.value();
    }
}
```

And add adapter to Status where you used.

```
@XmlElement(name = "Status", required = true)
@XMLJavaTypeAdapter(StatusAdapter.class)
private Status status;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices and the XMLAdapter: that was what I needed